# Second-level aggregation in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a simple example:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame(
  {"F1" : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
   "F2" : [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2], 
   "F3" : ['xx', 'yy', 'zz', 'zz', 'zz', 'xx', 'yy', 'zz', 'zz', 'zz']}) 
DF
```

How can I improve the code so that in the F3-unique column, in addition to the list of unique values of the F3 column in the group, the number of appearances of these values in the group is displayed like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried and what's not working? Please include your code, any errors you're encountering, and improve the description of exactly what you're hoping to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use `.groupby()` + `.sum()` + `value_counts()` + `.agg()`:

```
df2 = DF.groupby('F1')['F2'].sum()
df3 = (DF.groupby(['F1', 'F3'])['F3']
         .value_counts()
         .reset_index([2], name='count')
         .apply(lambda x: x['F3'] + '-' + str(x['count']), axis=1)
      )
df4 = df3.groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)
df4.name = 'F3'
df_out = pd.concat([df2, df4], axis=1).reset_index()
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

  F1  F2              F3
0  A   4  xx-1 yy-1 zz-1
1  B   7       xx-1 zz-2
2  C   8       yy-1 zz-3
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like [`groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html)'s named aggregation + python's [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) could work well here:

```
from collections import Counter


df2 = DF.groupby('F1', as_index=False).aggregate({
    'F2': 'sum',
    'F3': lambda g: ' '.join([f'{k}-{v}' for k, v in Counter(g).items()])
})
```

`df2`:

```
  F1  F2              F3
0  A   4  xx-1 yy-1 zz-1
1  B   7       zz-2 xx-1
2  C   8       yy-1 zz-3
```

---

aggregating to a Counter turns a collection into a dictionary based on the number of unique values:

```
df2 = DF.groupby('F1', as_index=False).aggregate({
    'F2': 'sum',
    'F3': Counter
})
```

```
  F1  F2                           F3
0  A   4  {'xx': 1, 'yy': 1, 'zz': 1}
1  B   7           {'zz': 2, 'xx': 1}
2  C   8           {'yy': 1, 'zz': 3}
```

The surrounding comprehension is used to reformat the data display:

Sample with 1 row:

```
' '.join([f'{k}-{v}' for k, v in Counter({'xx': 1, 'yy': 1, 'zz': 1}).items()])
```

```
xx-1 yy-1 zz-1
```